# what means for this powerpc instruction?

Tags: assembly, gnu, powerpc

this instruction is from powerpc uboot .

```
lis r3 CONFIG_SYS_DEFAULT_IMMR@h
```

particularly **"@h"** what mean?

another insruction:

```
lwz r4,0(r3)
```

particularly **"0(r3)"** what mean?

thanks!

Comment: I have known the mean of "lwz r4,0(r3)":
put the value in address (r3+0) to r4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lis r3,CONFIG_SYS_DEFAULT_IMMR@h`

Loads the high (upper) halfword (16 bits) of the immediate operand into the upper halfword of `r3`. The `@h` suffix is used to specify the high halfword of `CONFIG_SYS_DEFAULT_IMMR`.

For example, if `CONFIG_SYS_DEFAULT_IMMR` is equal to `0x12345678` the above instruction would load `0x1234` into the upper halfword of `r3`.

---

```
lwz r4,0(r3)
```

Loads a word (32 bits) from the effective address (`r3+0`) into `r4`. If `r4` is a 64-bit register it would additionally clear the upper word of `r4`.

Comment: where can I find document for "@h"?

does it in gnu binutils document, or powerpc instruction format

Comment: You can find descriptions of `@h` [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-ppc/) or [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-powasm1/index.html). It's an operator for the assembler, so it's not part of the instruction encoding.